# Selecting a whole word with CTRL + SHIFT + arrow keys

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have the habbit to select a whole word by standing at the first character of the word and doing `CTRL + SHIFT + right arrow key`. But when the word has capitals then it stops at each capital.

Can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: This behavior depends on the text editor you are using. What is it?

Comment: How your question concerned to c#?

Comment: Yes sorry I changed the tag. Visual Studio 2010

Comment: This is not the case in most text editors, please specify the setup you are using.

Comment: Resharper? Disable camelhumps.

Comment: Yes It's with Resharper. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ReSharper 7, here's where I found how to disable CamelHumps.

[image: Environment -> Editor -> Use CamelHumps]